# Formula to determine the range of signed and unsigned data types C++

Tags: c++, math

I'm just starting out in C++ (literally my second day) and I've been assigned to calculate the ranges of the varying data types, signed and unsigned. The problem is, the way my school works I won't get to the Math portion where he teaches us the formula for another couple months. He said to get the information from someone who has done the math course already however all of them said they're going to work on this from home where they have their notes. So now I'm left in the dark with google and its inconclusive answers, so I ask you, the wise folk of stackoverflow.

What are the formulas for getting the range of the data types? I have found one for INT that has worked but does not apply to the others, the ones he wants us to calculate are: char, short, long, and long long. He also wants the unsigned versions of those 4 as well as INT.

We already have the size in bits and bytes of each of these data types.

Here is how I have my INT range laid out:

```
    printf ("\nThe range of int is: %f\n", pow(2, (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) -1));
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## `std::numeric_limits<T>`

You can get the actual values of these limits using these functions:

- [`T std::numeric_limits<T>::min()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min)
- [`T std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)

You substitute the appropriate type in place of `T`, such as `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

## Formulas

The formulas for a signed number with N bits (using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)) are

- min = -1 * 2<sup>N - 1</sup>
- max = 2<sup>N - 1</sup> - 1

The formulas for an unsigned number with N bits are

- min = 0
- max = 2<sup>N</sup> - 1

## Example: 8-bit `char`

The `char` has N = 8 bits. Let's verify these formulas with `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

- `signed char`

  - min = -1 * 2<sup>N - 1</sup> = -1 * 2<sup>7</sup> = -128
  - max = 2<sup>N - 1</sup> - 1 = 2<sup>7</sup> - 1 = 127
- `unsigned char`

  - min = 0
  - max = 2<sup>N</sup> - 1 = 2<sup>8</sup> - 1 = 255

Comment: Remember that `^` is the bitwise xor operator; C++ has no exponentiation operator. But `2**N` can be written as `1<<N`.

Comment: @KeithThompson You're misinterpreting the equations I've written. They're math, not C++...

Comment: I know what you mean. I just want to make sure everyone else does, or at least that nobody tries to use `^` in C++ code for exponentation. (You might consider using 2<sup>n</sup> notation for superscripts; it works in answers, but not in comments.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Oh, I was misinterpreting your comment then. :) Good suggestion, I'm changing it to use `<sup>`.

Comment: I would add a note about two's complement, for the signed case. Also, `char` has no guarantee to be `signed` nor `unsigned` unless you specify explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for this, I got some outrageously large numbers and they all seem to line up with what I have found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

Answer (score 3):

In actuality, those ranges can be found in `<limits>` - see [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/), and specifically the template `std::numeric_limits` - see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). I'm assuming though that you want to know where those numbers come from.

What matters is the number of bits. If you have `n` bits, then you can express 2<sup>n</sup> different values with them. Take an old-school 16-bit integer. With 16 bits, the amount of possible different values is 2<sup>16</sup> = 65536. If you have an unsigned value, you're only expressing non-negative values. So the smallest value you express is 0, and the largest is 2<sup>n</sup> - 1, so a 16-bit unsigned integer goes from `0` to `65535`.

If you are expressing integers with a sign, then of course you now have the same amount of values (65536 in the previous example) to express some positive and negative numbers. You've got `0` in the middle, and then you split the remaining values between negatives and positives. So you get `-32768` on the low end and `32767` on the high end.

For any other datatype that represents an integer, it's the same pattern, whether it's 32, 64 or more bits.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Thank you for the superscripts, I couldn't find that formatting.

Comment: `numeric_limits` comes from `<limits>`. The `<climits>` brings in the C macros for the same purpose.