# Calculating the range of long in C using formula

Tags: c

I'm working on Exercise 2-1 in K&R, and part of that exercise is determining the range of the long data type by printing out the values from limits.h *and* calculating them.

When I print out the values from limits.h, I get the minimum value for long being -9223372036854775808 and the maximum value for long being 9223372036854775807.

I wasn't exactly sure how to calculate the range, but using the formula from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112281/formula-to-determine-the-range-of-signed-and-unsigned-data-types-c) seems to work for char, int, and short: [data type range forumlas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7wfk.png).

When I use the above formulas, I get the minimum value for long being -9223372036854775808 and the maximum value for long being 9223372036854775808.

You're probably thinking that I just forgot to subtract 1 from the maximum value, but in fact I do subtract one. These are my statements for printing and calculating the min and max values for long:

```
printf("min val of long: %.0f\n", pow(2, sizeof(long) * 8) / -2);
printf("max val of long: %.0f\n\n", (pow(2, sizeof(long) * 8) / 2) - 1);
```

Does anyone understand why there is a discrepancy between the max value which I printed out from limits.h and the max value which I calculated?

Comment: To debug this, I suggest breaking the formula into smaller parts and printing each one. For example print `sizeof(long)` and `sizeof(long) * 8` separately. Continue in this way with the rest of the parts of the formula. Then calculate each of these by hand to see if the results are what you expect.

Comment: The code you give is **not** the same as the formulas given in the first answer of the question that you linked. While they are mathematically equivalent, remember that you are using `long` here, not actual real numbers in the math sense. You have to be careful of overflow. This means that you should do `2^(n-1)` rather than the mathematically equivalent `2^n/2`.

Comment: The moral of the story is that `long` is an approximation of the mathematical idea of "integer". They are not the same thing, so not all of the rules of mathematics apply in all cases. In particular, `long` has limited values (as you are calculated here) unlike "integer", so when you do a calculation that reaches the maximum value of a long, you will get unexpected results.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice OP is not using integers, this is a floating point computation. Overflow has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Acorn Thanks for the correction. The underlying concept is still valid: numeric datatypes are not the same as the mathematical Platonic forms that they approximate. I had in mind `long` vs "integer", but the same general caveat applies to `float` and `double` vs "real numbers" as you describe in your answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Certainly! I didn't intend to convey the opposite :)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for the detailed response. I tried using 2^(n-1) instead and ended up with the exact same number. Do you mostly agree with Acorn's answer then? I think I understand what you're saying about these data types being representations of numbers and not always behaving exactly like we would expect.

Comment: @awinston Yes, Acorn's answer is accurate since `pow()` works with `double`, not long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you don't see the value you expect is because the sequence of representable values in a typical `double` (returned by `pow()`) is:

```
...
9223372036854774784
9223372036854775808
9223372036854777856
...
```

That is, a `double` (IEEE 754) does not have enough bits of mantissa to represent the integer you are expecting. `9223372036854775808` is one of the integers that can be represented exactly because it is a power of 2.

If you want to get the maximum value, you can carefully convert your formula to the integer domain and the `<<` operator:

```
const long x = (1UL << (sizeof(long) * 8 - 1)) - 1;
printf("%li\n", x);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this helps a lot. So I assume that it's just a coincidence that the true max value of long happens to be 1 away from the closest value representable by a double?

Comment: @awinston: It is not completely a coincidence; the numbers representable in any floating-point  format using a base of 2 are all integer multiples of powers of 2 (including 2 to negative integer powers). So any power of two within range is representable in such a floating-point format. Since the maximum value representable in some binary integer is one less than some power of two, it is at most one away from a value representable in a `double`. (It can be closer if the numbers representable in a double are close together at that point.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil That makes sense, thanks for clarifying!